# PHP Search Using Multiple Words

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I am trying to create a search function where a user can input two words into a text field and it will split the words and construct a MySQL query.

This is what I have so far.

```
$search     = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['text_field']);
$search     = explode(" ", $search);

foreach($search as $word)
{
    $where = "";
    $where      .= "product_code LIKE '%". $word ."%'";
    $where      .= "OR description LIKE '%". $word ."%'";

    $query      = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE $where";
    $result     = mysql_query($query) or die();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $customer['value']  = $row['id'];
            $customer['label']  = "{$row['id']}, {$row['name']} {$row['age']}";
            $matches[]          = $customer;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $customer['value']  = "";
        $customer['label']  = "No matches found.";
        $matches[]          = $customer;
    }
}

$matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 5); //return only 5 results
```

It constructs and runs the query, but returns funny results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what funny results are

Comment: Any reason you can't use a fulltext index for this? Using `like '%...%'` precludes the use of indexes and performance will be horrible on big tables. And what's "funny results"? Did they make you laugh? As well, you should be escaping the individual words, not the string BEFORE you manipulate it

Answer (score 1):

1. MySQL has something called `LIMIT`, so you last row would be needless.
2. Use Full-Text-Search for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html - It's faster and more elegant

Comment: His last row is still valid, in that if he has 10 results total from the queries, he only wants to show 5 of them. LIMIT restricts the results from each query. Granted, just choosing the first 5 $matches isn't great results either, but just a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is on MyISAM table format you could do a Fulltext search on the columns you are interested as Sn0opy mentioned already

Personally I believe that when it comes to mySQL if you actually want to create a great search engine use Sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/) or Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

There may be a learning curve on both of them, but the results are professional.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of anything more specific than "funny results"?  Off the cuff there are several possibilities but it really depends upon the results that are being returned.  My PHP is a bit rusty so I will apologize up front if my brain throws in some java rules instead, but at first blush...

Name the array something other than $search.  It probably isn't the problem, but it looks odd to have the array created by explode() carry the name of the string being exploded. Try something like $searched = explode(" ", $search); and then use $searched in the subsequent foreach() loop.

What if the user only puts in one search term?  If there is no space in $text_field then explode will return an empty array, which should thoroughly jack up your query.  You should at least verify that there is a space in $text_field before exploding $search.  Likewise, what if the user enters two search terms, but one of the terms is two words separated by a space?  Again you are going to get "funny results" because you will get results that you don't want along with duplicated results as the query extends itself to both of the words in a term individually.

Without knowing more of what you mean by "funny results" it is really difficult to trouble shoot this one.